# Installed Chrome manually, now cant uninstall it

Tags: google-chrome, software-uninstall

I installed Chrome manually, but now I can't find it anywhere but in the search box. I tried to install Chrome again, but it installed without any hesitation and if I try to uninstall Chrome, it only uninstalls the latest. I can't find it in either the Snap software app or in the Software app.

Both Chromes on search box:

[image: Both Chromes on search box]

Packages installed:

[image: Packages installed]

Uninstalling Chrome:

[image: Uninstalling chrome]

Still one Chrome is showing:

[image: Still one chrome showing]

It still works:

[image: It still works]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text.

Comment: It looks like you had it installed twice using two different methods. Do you remember how you installed it?

Comment: I installed it manually, using the method described on the official page from google: downloading the package and installing with the software center. The second time i installed it with the same method, and it showed on the software center. Maybe i can delete some folders to make it dont open again as the default browser? Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you are unable to uninstall Chrome, try deleting the Chrome directory /opt/google/chrome/.
Also, if you want to change the default browser, go to “Settings”. Select “Default Applications” in the left sidebar and choose the default browser under the “Web” drop-down.

Comment: On /opt/ i only have a folder called containerd